# Exception in Pure Ruby Application

Tags: ruby

I have the following ruby class:

```
class Money
  attr_accessor :amount, currency

  def initialize(amount, currency)
    @amount = amount
    @currency = currency
  end
end
```

Let's say I create an instance of that class like that:

```
money = Money.new(0, 'BR')
```

It's obvious that I should not be able to create a money with an amount less than or equal than 0. In that case, I would like to create a Custom Exception for my class. What's the best way to do it in a pure ruby application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also create it inside `Money` class, like this:

```
class Money
  InvalidAmountError = Class.new(StandardError)

  attr_accessor :amount, :currency

  def initialize(amount, currency)
    raise InvalidAmountError, "Amount must be greater than 0" if amount <= 0

    @amount = amount
    @currency = currency
  end
end
```

Testing it:

```
> Money.new(0, 'BR')
> Money::InvalidAmountError: Amount must be greater than 0
```

Comment: What is the reason for using dynamic class creation instead of just `class InvalidAmountError < StandardError; end`?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Just a matter of style, i try to follow this [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/blob/master/README.md#single-line-classes) whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
class InvalidCurrency < StandardError
  ... some logic
end

class Money
  attr_accessor :amount, currency

  def initialize(amount, currency)
    raise InvalidCurrency unless amount > 0
    @amount = amount
    @currency = currency
  end
end
```

checkout [this blog](http://blog.honeybadger.io/ruby-custom-exceptions/) for more details